# Accounting for Special Characters in ASCII

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii, data-science

I am trying to filter non-English apps out of a data set for a problem I am working on.

How can non-English apps be removed from the data set? An initial approach will be to check whether the string can be encoded with only ASCII characters. If the string cannot be encoded with only ASCII characters, then the string has characters from some other alphabet or special characters.

Testing this approach on some toy examples yields:

```
def is_english(app_name):
try:
    app_name.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    return False
else:
    return True

print(is_english('Instagram'))
print(is_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播'))
print(is_english('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite'))
print(is_english('Instachat '))
```

Obviously, there is an issue with the initial approach, namely that 'Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite' and 'Instachat ', both English apps, are being recognized as non-English apps because they have special characters (i.e. '™' and '').

Any suggestions on how to allow for special characters like '™', Emojis, etc.?

Comment: What do you mean by non-English? For example, what about other languages that use Latin script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a function that calculates how many chars are probably English characters and return True above a certain threshold. Still not a 100% perfect (think of e.g. German words that share the same letters like `Tastatur` [keyboard]) but maybe a start:

```
import re
def is_probably_english(app_name, threshold=0.9):
    rx = re.compile(r'[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]')
    ascii = [char for char in app_name if rx.search(char)]
    quotient = len(ascii) / len(app_name)
    passed = True if quotient >= threshold else False
    return passed, quotient


print(is_probably_english('Instagram'))
print(is_probably_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播'))
print(is_probably_english('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite'))
print(is_probably_english('Instachat '))
```

This yields

```
(True, 1.0)
(False, 0.3157894736842105)
(True, 0.9655172413793104)
(True, 0.9090909090909091)
```

Comment: This was the suggestion made in the instructions, but I was hoping there was a better way. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3727648: Well, the approach is not too bad, is it? I doubt that there's a fundamentally better way. Maybe replace every emoticon or sth.

Comment: I think it's a brilliant approach. Now I just need to figure out how to filter a Pandas DataFrame using the approach. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3727648: Pose another question and link from here. Maybe we can help.

Comment: Will do if I can't figure it out. Want to try solving it on my own first :) Thank you!

Comment: Here's what I did with your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63327220/filtering-a-pandas-dataframe-using-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
def is_english(app_name):
   y = app_name.encode()
   return len(app_name) == len(y)
```

- https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len
- https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode

Comment: Returns False for case 3 and 4 which OP will certainly want.

Answer (score 0):

- You could investigate whether you can get hold of dictionaries for various world languages (e.g. spellchecking dictionaries). When a word in the name of an app is not an English word, see if it's in one of the foreign language dictionaries. If so, it's more likely to be a foreign app.
- You could look at what script the name is written in. This would rule out your example where the name consists mostly of CJK characters.
- You could apply your current approach, but filter out characters from certain Unicode categories first (like characters that are "symbols").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the unicode database to get character class and name. For instance, "T" is category "Lu" for letter upper case, and name "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T". The full set of categories is documented at https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html. This example accepts Latin letters, digit numbers and all other types. It likely needs refinement to catch more cases.

```
import unicodedata

# See unicode categories at 
# https://unicodebook.readthedocs.io/unicode.html#categories

def is_englishy(c):
    """Is character expected in english text"""
    category = unicodedata.category(c)
    if category.startswith("L"):
        # letter. accept latin
        name = unicodedata.name(c)
        return name.startswith("LATIN")
    if category.startswith("N"):
        # number. accept digit
        name = unicodedata.name(c)
        return name.startswith("DIGIT")
    # accepting everything else
    return True

def is_english(app_name):
    return all(is_englishy(c) for c in app_name)

print(is_english('Instagram'))
print(is_english('爱奇艺PPS -《欢乐颂2》电视剧热播'))
print(is_english('Docs To Go™ Free Office Suite'))
print(is_english('Instachat '))
```