# Filtering a Pandas DataFrame Using a Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

This question is related to the question I posted yesterday, which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321047/accounting-for-special-characters-in-ascii/63321154?noredirect=1#comment111978414_63321154).

So, I went ahead and implemented the solution provided by Jan to the entire data set. The solution is as follows:

```
import re

def is_probably_english(row, threshold=0.90):
    regular_expression = re.compile(r'[-a-zA-Z0-9_ ]')
    ascii = [character for character in row['App'] if regular_expression.search(character)]
    quotient = len(ascii) / len(row['App'])
    passed = True if quotient >= threshold else False
    return passed

google_play_store_is_probably_english = google_play_store_no_duplicates.apply(is_probably_english, axis=1)

google_play_store_english = google_play_store_no_duplicates[google_play_store_is_probably_english]
```

So, from what I understand, we are filtering the google_play_store_no_duplicates DataFrame using the is_probably_english function and storing the result, which is a boolean, into another DataFrame (google_play_store_is_probably_english). The google_play_store_is_probably_english is then used to filter out the non-English apps in the google_play_store_no_duplicates DataFrame, with the end result being stored in a new DataFrame.

Does this make sense and does it seem like a sound way to approach the problem? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes sense, I think this is the best way to do it, the result of the function is a boolean as you said and then when you apply it in a `pd.Series` you end up with a `pd.Series` of booleans, which is usually called a boolean mask. This concept can be very useful in pandas when you want to filter rows by some parameters.

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/boolean-indexing-in-pandas/) is an article about boolean masks in pandas.